# ServiceStack: How to deserialize to dynamic object

Tags: servicestack-text

Tried using `JsonSerializer.DeserializeFromString<ExpandoObject>(data)` and it does not work. Can one deserialize into dynamic, or is SS not capable of doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not supported by ServiceStack serializer. You may get it working to a degree if you were to compile the serializer in .NET 4.0 like [suggested by Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13717267/205859). NuGet package only contains .NET 3.5 build. I think it's not worth the trouble. Best would be to use JSON.NET in this case. Here's an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9326146/205859).